# Count of observers in a Rx Subject

Tags: system.reactive

With Rx, what is the best way to get the number of current observers in a Subject?

I have a scenario where I want to publish a message, but only if there are observers.  If there are no observers, I need to do something else.

To get around this issue, what I've done is created my own ISubject implementation and expose a count of an internal IObserver collection.  I'm sure there must be an out of the box way of doing this, I'm just not fully familiar with what Rx has to offer.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you care if you have observers or not?

Comment: It's not so much that I care that I have an observer, as much as caring when I don't have an observer. 

In my application I have windows that handle certain messages.  They are the observers.  If no windows are open, I create a new one.  So I need to know when I have no observers in order to create a new window.

Comment: That sounds like logic you would put into the observer (whatever it is that's doing your window management); putting it into the thing your observing seems like a bad design decision.

Comment: I have to agree with @casperOne here. This is generally supposed to be expressed in a form where subscription builds the pipeline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid implementing your own observable (or subject) implementations whenever possible.

You could certainly try writing a wrapper class to help.

Try this:

```
public class Countable
{
    private int _count;
    public int Count { get { return _count; } }
    public IObservable<T> GetCountable<T>(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
            var subscription = source.Subscribe(o);
            var decrement = Disposable.Create(() =>
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
            });
            return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, decrement);
        });
    }
}
```

You can then write code like this:

```
var xs = new Subject<int>();
var countable = new Countable();
var ys = countable.GetCountable(xs);
Console.WriteLine(countable.Count);
var s1 = ys.Subscribe(y => { });
Console.WriteLine(countable.Count);
var s2 = ys.Subscribe(y => { });
Console.WriteLine(countable.Count);
s1.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine(countable.Count);
s2.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine(countable.Count);
```

My results running this are:

```
0
1
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the `Subject<T>.HasObservers` property.

[Source Code](https://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Subjects/Subject.cs)

I don't recall exactly when it was introduced, but I'm pretty sure that it wasn't always there.  It was probably added in Rx 2.0.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting to note that if you use this in a doOnUnsubscribe, it will always return true, afaict

Answer (score 4):

use  `subject.observers.length`, example:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs'

let subject = new Subject()
let s1 = subject.subscribe(v => console.log('observerA: ' + v))

subject.next(1) // observerA: 1
console.log(subject.observers.length) // 1


let s2 = subject.subscribe(v => {
    console.log('observerB: ' + v)
    if(v===3) s2.unsubscribe()
})

subject.next(2) // observerA: 2
console.log(subject.observers.length) // 2

subject.next(3) // observerA: 3
console.log(subject.observers.length) // 1
```

Comment: I don't know if this works in RxJS, but even if it does, it's not part of the standard Rx spec. If I saw this in prod, I'd tend to think it was a hack.

Comment: Just came here to say that this is the right solution (not a hack, @forresthopkinsa). Here is the manual entry: [Subject.observers](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject#observers)

Comment: Again, not part of the standard Rx spec. The right way to do what the OP wants (do A if there are observers, B if there are none) is with `.HasObservers`.

Comment: `subject.observers` seems to be deprecated:
Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. Will be made internal in v8.