# Is there a Rx.Net Operator that tells the number of subscribed observers?

Tags: system.reactive

I am trying to debug if I am correctly disposing the observers to a long running services (services exposing `IObservable`). And I am wondering if there an operator or something that we can create to log the number of active observers, say something like.

```
public class NewsService
{
    IObservable<Article> GetArticles();
} 


NewsService.Instance
    .GetArticles()
    .DoCount(x=> Trace.Writeline("The current count is {x}"))
    .Subscribe();
```

There is a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637437/1139856), which works on the Subject. What if we don't have access to the Subject and a library is exposing `IObservable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the concept of subscriber count for an arbitrary observable sequence is not defined.

For cold observables such as `Observable.Interval`, every time you subscribe to the observable, a new pipeline instance is created, which - from its point of view sees only a single observer at a time.

We can, nonetheless, warm up a cold observable, and watch subscriptions come and go.

```
    public static IObservable<T> RefCount<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<int> onChange)
    {
        var subscribers = 0;
        var shared = source.Publish().RefCount();
        void callback(int count) => onChange(Interlocked.Add(ref subscribers, count));

        return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
        {
            callback(+1);
            var subscription = shared.Subscribe(observer);
            var dispose = Disposable.Create(() => callback(-1));

            return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, dispose);
        });
    }
```

**Demo**

```
        var values = 
            Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
            .RefCount(count => Console.WriteLine($"Subscribers: {count}"));

        values.Take(5).Subscribe();
        values.Take(10).Subscribe();
        values.Take(15).Subscribe();
```

**Output**

```
Subscribers: 1
Subscribers: 2
Subscribers: 3
Subscribers: 2
Subscribers: 1
Subscribers: 0
```

Now, this works because we have a shared view of the parent observable.
So try to make all subscriptions point to the same instance.

```
_articles = GetArticles().RefCount(count => Console.WriteLine($"Subscribers: {count}")));
...
_articles.Subscribe();
```